# Stopping wx.CallLater loop function

Tags: wxpython

I have a function that uses wx.CallLater to call another function every 10 seconds until the returned answer = 6 which is working fine.

What I'm now trying to do is to break out of this loop early if wanted using a button press from a gui

```
    def confirmTimer(self):
        txid = utility.read_txid()
        confirms = utility.pConfirms(self.params['paddress'])

        if confirms < 6:
            print "the timer has started"
            wx.CallLater(10000, self.confirmTimer) #increase to 10000 after testing

        self.confirm_count.SetLabel(str(confirms))
        self.cgauge.SetValue(int(confirms))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have another variable that that you set to True, Add it to your condition so it will only do CallLater if both your existing condition and the new one is True, When you click you button change the new variable to False.